# finding files that end in .html in ENTIRE hard drive?

Tags: linux, terminal, command

I can find the files that end in ".html" in my current directory very easily by doing: 
**find *.html**
but how can I search the entire HDD for these files without backing out of the directory?

Comment: I guess you mean "all mounted filesystems" instead of "entire hard drive". BTW: `find *.html` is a really idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would search in e.g. `/proc` and `/sys`, too:

```
find / -type f -name '*.html'
```

You can limit the search to a filesystem but then you have to pass the root of each mounted filesystem to be searched:

```
find / /home /tmp -xdev -type f -name '*.html'
```

Comment: I'm assuming I don't need the **-type f** for it to work, but this is the answer! thankyou!!!

Comment: @nismoasfuh Usually only files will have `*.html` names but it makes sense to do it right.